# Find duplicate lines python

Tags: python, linux

I have a problem to find duplicates and only print those duplicates. I have a text file that I open and trying to find duplicates and print those.

What I have as long is:

A file which is called data1.txt, the file contains some line:

```
G1/0/1    fc:3f:db:8d:fd:6c
G1/0/1    38:63:bb:bb:f8:7d
G1/0/2    30:e1:71:7a:27:3b
G1/0/3    40:a8:f0:53:6f:31
```

How could I make a script that only find duplicates on the first world and print the output like this:

```
G1/0/1    fc:3f:db:8d:fd:6c
G1/0/1    38:63:bb:bb:f8:7d
```

I don't need to see those other lines which is single.

Comment: How many maximum no of record in file, any limit?

Comment: No, any limit yet. Thanks Lalit

Comment: Are duplicates always going to be consecutive? Or can they appear with other entries in between? When should they be reported, the moment you have detected at least two entries?

Comment: And what should be the output when you have more than two lines with the same identifier, should *all* lines with the same identifier be reported?

Comment: No, it can come on the different lines. I just need when the are more then one one, it does not matter if they are consecutive or not. Thanks Martijn

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)

with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:                      #Iterate each line
        val = line.strip().split()           #Get first word
        res[val[0]].append(line)

for k, v in res.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        print(v)
```

**Output:**

```
['G1/0/1    fc:3f:db:8d:fd:6c\n', 'G1/0/1    38:63:bb:bb:f8:7d\n']
```

Comment: It's overkill to remember *all* entries when you only have to track that you have seen things before.

Comment: Yes..that is true :(

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. That is what i needed. Thanks again

Comment: Then again, they do want to show the actual lines duplicated, so forget about my remark.

Answer (score -2):

```
a = """
fafafafa
fawcsacaw
fafafafa
"""

arr = []

for line in a.split("\n"):
  if line not in arr:
     arr.append(line)
  else:
     print(line + " is duplicated")
```

Comment: Testing against a list with `line in arr` or `line not in arr` takes O(N) linear time, so as the list grows, the test becomes slower and slower. This means that the whole program ends up taking *quadratic time*, getting slower as the number of lines grow. This is not a good choice. You should **at least** use a set or dictionary, instead. Next, you are not splitting of the identifier, so you can only find *whole lines* that are duplicated.